# One's Mother is one's Female parent

Tags: logic

Is below a correct predicate in logic for the english statement

"One's Mother is one's female parent"

Where Mother(x,y) denotes Y is mother of X.

Female(X) denotes X is a female

Parent(X,Y) denotes Y is a parent of X.

The solution for the above question was given to be this

$\forall x \forall yMother(x,y) \leftrightarrow (Female(x)\land Parent(x,y))$

Where the domain for X and Y consists of all people in the world.

I think the correct expression must be

$\forall x \forall y\bigl(Mother(x,y) \leftrightarrow(Female(x) \land Parent(x,y)) \bigr)$

Please let me know which expression is correct.

Comment: CORRECT. The scope of the leading quantifiers must be the complete formula.

Comment: It is correct of course, but don't post it this question on any sociology site. Gender theorists won't agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in $\forall x \forall yMother(x,y) \leftrightarrow (Female(x)\land Parent(x,y))$ proposition the right $x$ and $y$ are free variable this cannot be true. Because the right $x$ and $y$ can have other value of the left $x$ and $y$. Hence, You can't conclude that $Mother(Marta, Jack) \leftrightarrow Female(Melody) \land Mother(Melody, John)$! Hence, the second statement ($\forall x \forall y\bigl(Mother(x,y) \leftrightarrow(Female(x) \land Parent(x,y)) \bigr)$) could be true based on the defined model.